# Do I still need to use background thread if I use coroutine to read/write Realm in Android to avoid blocking UI?

Tags: android, realm, kotlin-coroutines

I have question in my head and I don't know how to test it.

Assume I have a function `getData`, which loads the data from a realm object and it takes 5 seconds.

Without coroutine, I need to call this method in background thread to avoid blocking UI.

If I change `getData` to suspend function, and I call it on the main thread, will it still freeze the UI thread for 5 seconds? Or will it be like calling delay(5000) inside the `getData` function, won't block the UI thread?

I want to create a simple project to validate this but I don't have data big enough to produce 5 seconds delay.

Comment: Although if getting your data from Realm takes 5 seconds, then I'm curious about the amount of data you have. Realm doesn't like being tossed around between threads because it's thread-confined, but the queries are *supposed* to be fairly lazy.

Answer (score 2):

> If I change `getData` to `suspend` function, and I call it on the main thread, will it still freeze the UI thread for 5 seconds?

Yes, coroutines can't undo the fact that a given piece of code makes a blocking function call. This is the typical idiom you can use to hand off a blocking call to a background thread and then continue working with it on the UI thread:

```
myScope.launch {
    val result = withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
        // blocking call here
    }
    // use the result to update the GUI here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it depends on what you mean by

> If I change `getData` to suspend function

- If you just add keyword `suspend` to the function, it will change nothing, i.e. thread will be blocked till you get a response.
- If you re-write function to be 'suspendable', then it will

  1. trigger the request
  2. suspend itself (without blocking the thread)
  3. resume after response received

You may use `suspendCoroutine` function from Coroutines library to achieve this.

The abstract example can be something as below:

```
suspend fun getData(): String = suspendCoroutine { continuation ->

        // 1. Trigger event
        serverApi.getData().onResult(

            // 3. Resume either with data or error, after callback received from serverApi
            onSuccess = {
                continuation.resume("Data") 
            },
            onError = {
                continuation.resume("Error")
            } 
        )

        // 2. Suspend after block is finished
    }
```

P.S. Probably in your case (get data from db) above will not work, as there is nothing to suspend (function is busy all the time, unlike with network requests).